# AWS Lambda to use caller identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

In a mobile App, I want a lambda function to be able to access only rows in the DynamoDB where the key is the userId which calls the Lambda.
I've set the below policy, but I keep getting

```
User: arn:aws:sts::XXX:assumed-role/FederatedIdentityRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXX:table/UserData
```

Any hints are welcome.
Thanks

Below is the Lambda's policy:

```
{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXX:table/UserData"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your issue is around your use of "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605419/aws-s3-transfer-manager-cognito-identity-amazonaws-comsub-policy-variable-ac

Comment: Well, I just found out that the ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} doesn't really refer to the 'sub' field in the authetication token you get from cognito user pool, but rather to the IdentityId you get from the the identityPool for that user!!

Answer (score -1):

I just found out that the `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` doesn't really refer to the `sub` field in the authentication token you get from cognito user pool, but rather to the `IdentityId` you get from the the `identityPool` for that user!